# How can I print easyadmin datagrid Crud::PAGE_INDEX page data

Tags: javascript, symfony, datagrid, easyadmin

How can I print all or selected rows on the Symfony EasyAdmin CRUD Datagrid page to retrieve the data from the grid component?

Is there a printing library available or does the browser's print functionality exist to generate a print preview or directly print the data?